# Find rows in one table which don't appear multiple times in link table

Tags: mysql

I have multiple sites and when a user registers on one site we automatically create an account for them on several sites.

Our "central" database which manages this has a clients table, a sites table and then a clients_sites table as the link.

```
clients table
-------------
id | name
1  | Larry
2  | Curly
```

```
sites table
-----------
id | url
1  | http://one.com
2  | http://two.com
```

```
clients_sites
--------------
id | clients_id | sites_id
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 1          | 2
3  | 2          | 1
```

I need to find an efficient query to find clients who aren't listed in the link table for each site.

So in this example Curly is not listed in site two.

Is there a single SQL query to find clients where they don't appear in the link table for each site?

Comment: Not tested, but something like this should work
    `SELECT * FROM clients
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT clients_id FROM clients_sites)`

Comment: Thanks Martin, that wouldn't work for me because the client's id may be in the link table for one or more of the sites but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can consider all possible **combinations** of a `clients_id` with `sites_id`, using `Cross Join` in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- Now, we can use an "anti-join" to consider only those "combinations" where there is no matching row found in the `clients_sites` table, using `Left Join` and `clients_sites.id IS NULL` (no matching row)

Try the following query:

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM 
(SELECT c.id AS clients_id, 
        c.name AS clients_name, 
        s.id AS sites_id, 
        s.url AS sites_url 
 FROM clients AS c 
 CROSS JOIN sites AS s 
) AS dt 
LEFT JOIN clients_sites AS cs 
  ON cs.clients_id = dt.clients_id AND 
     cs.sites_id = dt.sites_id 
WHERE cs.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, that helps a lot. I was selecting all from the clients table before and just looping over it but this table has grown to many thousands of rows already and will continue to grow by a few thousand each month so its taking impractically long. This solution work very well!